# Formula to determine whether a line form by 2 geo points (lat, lon) intersects geo region (circle)?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

It does not need to be very accurate. Does anyone know a good way to do this?

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: no, what class gives this kinda homework

Comment: How accurate is "not very"?   How is the circle defined (list of points vs. center and radius)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect

Comment: the region is defined by a center lat,lon point and a radius (in distance). accuracy is not very important: i wanted to check whether a driving path goes thru a geo region.

Comment: @Ryan your link does not tell me what i want

Answer (score 6):

When you say “it does not need to be very accurate” you don’t say *how* inaccurate a solution you’re prepared to accept. Also, you don’t say how big the geographic region under consideration is likely to be. These two criteria make a big difference to the kind of approach that needs to be taken.

With a small regions (a few kilometres, say), a flat approximation may be good enough (for example, the Mercator projection) and some of the other responses tell you how to do that. With larger regions you have to take the Earth’s sphericity into account. And if you want inaccuracy less than a percent or so, you need to take the eccentricity of Earth into account.

I’m going to assume for the purposes of this answer that a spherical approximation is good enough, and that your points are at similar enough altitudes that we don’t need to worry about their heights.

You can convert a geographical point (ψ, λ) to Cartesian Earth-centred coordinates using the transformation

> (ψ, λ) → (a cos(ψ) cos(λ), a cos(ψ) sin(λ), a sin(ψ))

where a is the mean radius of the Earth (6,371 km).  So let’s suppose that the two points that define your line are p₀ and p₁; then the shortest line through p₀ and p₁ is a great circle, which defines a plane that slices the Earth into two halves, with normal n = p₀ × p₁.

[image]

Now we need to find the border of the circular region. Suppose the centre of this region is at c and that the surface radius of the region is s.  Then the straight-line radius of the region is r = a sin(s/a). We’ll also need the true centre of the circular region, c’ = c cos(s/a).  (This point is buried deep underground!)

[image]

We’d like to intersect the two circles and solve for the points of intersection.  Unfortunately, because of numerical imprecision, the chances are that this procedure will never find any solutions because the imprecise circles will miss each other in 3 dimensions. So I suggest the following procedure: intersect the planes of the two circles, getting the dotted line shown below (unless c’ × n = 0 in which case the two circles are parallel and either c’ = o, in which case they are coincident, or else they do not intersect). Then intersect the line with the circular region.

[image]

This two-step procedure reduces the problem to two dimensions, and guarantees that a solution will be found even if numerical imprecision makes the two circles miss in 3 dimensions.

If you need more accuracy than this, then you might need to use [geodetic coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_system) on a reference ellipsoid such as [WGS 1984](http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/publications/tr8350.2/tr8350_2.html).

Answer (score 2):

I'd say [find the closest point on the line to the center of the circle,](https://web.archive.org/web/20060911063535/http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/%7Epbourke/geometry/pointline/) then determine whether that point is within the circle (i.e. the distance in question is less than or equal to the circle's radius).

Comment: sounds good, any ideas about the projection/conversion from lat,lon to 2d coordinates?

Comment: Chaos has it right. Unless I'm missing something, all the conversions wash out except the radius, which needs to be converted so that you're comparing apples to apples. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSegment.html for how to do that part.

Comment: No need to convert lat-lon to 2D coordinates; in fact that will probably just cause problems.  Find the closest point in 3D space.  The "line" becomes a great circle in 3D space.

Comment: This link fell off the internet

Answer (score 1):

Outline for solving the problem: assume the Earth is a sphere of radius one centered at the origin.  Convert all three lat, lon points to 3D coordinates.  The two points of the line plus the origin define a plane; intersect that plane with the sphere of radius d centered on the other point.  If there is no plane-sphere intersection, then the answer is the line does not intersect the region.  If there is a plane-sphere intersection, then the problem is simplified to intersecting the circular region defined by the plane-sphere intersection with the shortest circular arc on the plane going between the end points of the line and centered at the origin.  This is a straightforward 2D problem if you convert to the coordinate system of the plane.

Comment: If there is a plane-sphere intersection, then the answer is "yes".

Comment: Not true -- the plane might intersect while the circular arc on the plane we are actually interested in does not.

Answer (score 1):

This question is too vague to be answered precisely. What do you mean by

> a line form by 2 geo points (lat, lon)

This can be either a [great circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatCircle.html) going through them (also called orthodrome) or it a can be a linear function of spherical coordinates ([loxodrome](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Loxodrome.html)).

BTW, I assume your circle is a circle on the surface of the sphere, right?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming line is formed by points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), and circle has radius r with origin (0,0):

Calculate:
Incidence = r^2 * [(x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2] - (x1 * y2 - x2 * y1)^2

Then, from the value of Incidence, we can determine the following:
Incidence < 0: No intersection
Incidence = 0: Tangent (intersection at 1 point on circle)
Incidence > 0: Intersection

It's likely your circle is not at the origin (0,0), so to fix this, just add the origin coordinates from your line coordinates in the equation above. So, if the circle is at (x3, y3), x1 in the above equation would become x1 + x3. Likewise, y1 would be y1 + y3, and the same goes for x2 and y2.

For more info check out this [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-LineIntersection.html)

Comment: That's fine for points on a plane, but the earth is not flat.

Comment: But at what distance does it stop being fine. 1m? 1km? 100km?